# assembly basics - movq

Tags: assembly, x86-64

```
movq %rax,%rdx 

movq 13(%rax),%rdx 

movq 0x47(%rax,%rcx),%rdx 

rcx = 0000000000000030
rax = 0000000008048a37
```

I was wondering what's the difference between these three assembly line instructions. I know the first one is moving 8048a37 to %rdx. 
In the second one, I think I have to add 13 to 8048a37 to get 8048a4a and then whatever 8048a4a is pointing to gets moved to %rdx.
In the third one, I think I add rax, rdx, and 47 to get 8048aae and then whatever 8048aae is pointing to gets moved to %rdx.

Comment: The processor manuals are freely downloadable from both Intel and AMD. They include a comprehensive reference of all instructions and addressing modes.

Comment: Exactly. Your observations are correct.

Comment: Oh .. Didn't see your observations correctly . Sorry!!!

Answer (score 5):

The difference between those assembly instruction is that you are accessing the offset. Lets go through them :)

```
movq %rax,%rdx
```

Just moves rax register (64 bit register for eax bit) to rdx register (64 bit register for edx 32 bit)

```
movq 13(%rax),%rdx
```

Moves the address of rax register with an offset of 13 to rdx register

```
movq 0x47(%rax,%rcx),%rdx
```

Moves the address of 0x47 + rax register + rcx register to the rdx register.

Comment: The load effective address instruction (`lea`) would move the address. The description in the question is correct.

Answer (score 0):

`movq %rax, %rdx`
- Moves the content of the RAX register to the RDX register.

`movq 13(%rax), %rdx`
- Loads the 8-byte value in the address `[RAX + 13]` from memory to the RDX register.

`movq 0x47(%rax,%rcx),%rdx`
- Loads the 8-byte value in the address `[RAX + RCX + 0x47]` from memory to the RDX register.

Comment: No, the displacement (0x47) is not scaled by the operand-size.  Displacements in asm source are always in bytes.  (Fun fact: the machine encoding for AVX512 disp8 displacements is scaled by the operand-size, so you can reach +127 * 64 bytes with a compact displacement, but `vcmpeqps 13(%rax), %zmm1, %k1` (512-bit memory operand) would require a disp32 because 13 is not a multiple of 64.  But like I said, it doesn't affect how you write it in the source).